# Saving a spark Dataset to Apache Ignite with Array column and SaveMode.Overwrite

Tags: scala, apache-spark, ignite

I'm trying to save a Dataset to an Apache Ignite cache. I'm new to Ignite, but I think it will be very helpful for our use case. I've scoured the web for two days but can get this working. Here's what I have:

```
case class userXRef( @(QuerySqlField @field)(index = true) user_id:Long,
@(QuerySqlField @field)hwIds:Array[String])

// tinyDs: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[userXRef] just a test sample
tinyDs.write
    .format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE)
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE, "userXRef")
    .option("config", CONFIG)
    .option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS, "user_id")
    .save()
```

Generates this error:

```
org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Unsupported data type ArrayType(StringType,true)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryUtils$.dataType(QueryUtils.scala:151)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryUtils$.org$apache$ignite$spark$impl$QueryUtils$$compileColumn(QueryUtils.scala:96)
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(QueryUtils.scala:84)
  at     org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.QueryUtils$$anonfun$5.apply(QueryUtils.scala:84)
<snip>
```

If I create the table with SQL commands and use `.mode(SaveMode.Append)`

```
CREATE TABLE userXRef (user_id LONG, hwIds ARRAY, PRIMARY KEY(user_id));
CREATE INDEX idx_userXRef_user_id ON tapadIdfa (user_id);
```

I can save just fine.

I realize I can just do a DROP TABLE, CREATE TABLE, CREATE INDEX every time, but I'd prefer to just have the Dataset do the work if possible.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me, I sent a message to Ignite dev@ list to confirm: http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/DataFrame-integration-does-not-support-ARRAY-type-td33291.html. I think creating tables manually is a reasonable workaround at this point in case it works for you.

Comment: Thank you. Shortly after I posted this I noticed that reading the table back into a dataset also generates an error:

val newDS = spark.read.format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE).option("table", "userXRef").option("config", CONFIG).load()

java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.AttributeReference.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/types/DataType;ZLorg/apache/spark/sql/types/Metadata;Lorg/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/expressions/ExprId;Lscala/Option;)V
  at org.apache.ignite.spark.impl.optimization.package$.toAttributeReference...

Comment: It seems like trying to preserve the String Array as an ARRAY may not be fully supported. I'll probably just mkString them on the way in and split() them on the way back. It feels like extra processing that I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As the discussion on [developer list](http://apache-ignite-developers.2346864.n4.nabble.com/DataFrame-integration-does-not-support-ARRAY-type-td33291.html) has shown, it is a bug / missing feature: [IGNITE-9229](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-9229)

Answer (score 0):

How did you handle the nested json data in Apache Ignite table. 
I'm trying to write a dataframe(which contains `Array(String)` field) into Ignite table. And which fails with Exception

> org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: Unsupported data type
>   ArrayType(StringType,true)

```
Dataset NestedDF = spark.read().option("multiline","true").option("inferSchema","false").json("..../NestedInput_1.json");

Dataset NestedDF1= NestedDF.select(NestedDF.col("mandt"),NestedDF.col("customer"),NestedDF.col("milestones.milestone"),NestedDF.col("milestones.milestoneDateTime"));

NestedDF1.write().mode("append").format(IgniteDataFrameSettings.FORMAT_IGNITE()).option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CONFIG_FILE(),CONFIG).option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_TABLE(),"Nested_test").option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PRIMARY_KEY_FIELDS()("mandt")).option(IgniteDataFrameSettings.OPTION_CREATE_TABLE_PARAMETERS(), "template=replicated").save();

//Created "nested_test" table in ignite before loading writing dataframe into the Nested_test table with the below schema.

CREATE TABLE nested_test(
mandt varchar,
customer varchar,
milestones array,
PRIMARY KEY(mandt)
);

//And the Input data is like below.

{
   "mandt": "010",
   "customer": "HPE",
   "milestones": [
      {
         "milestone": "CustomerPoDt",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180303"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "OrderReceived",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180303"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "OrderCreated",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180330155355"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "ItemCreated",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180330173625"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "HeaderCleaned",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180330175004"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "ItemCleaned",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180402090822"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "Clean",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180402090822"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "ReleasedToProduction",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180424124601"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "ProductionDone",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180510153737"
      },
      {
         "milestone": "FactoryShippedToCustomer",
         "milestoneDateTime": "20180511101858"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I flattened it out into one field (e.g., string1,string2...) and planned to split it on reload. After weeks of trying I was never able to successfully save and read a dataframe from ignite. I figured I'd wait a couple versions and evaluate again. It does make a functional distributed key/value store though and we've been using it in that limited capacity.